# Can I continue solr indexing if an error occurs due to bad data instead of abort

Tags: solr, sunspot

We are using Primero and it uses Solr for search.

Below is the command to reindex

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex --trace
```

However, we get an error due to bad data that is hard to find. Is it possible to not abort and continue reindexing on error?

**Error message**

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Also, is it possible to get a detailed error?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Solr log should at least tell you what the error is (I'm guessing a malformed number for a numeric field or something like that, or a missing required field, etc.)

Comment: I have updated the question with the error message. It does not give the information on which data field etc.

Comment: That's not the Solr log - that's the sunspot/Ruby log. The Solr log is available from the admin page in Solr or from the `logs` directory on disk.

Comment: How do I see the solr admin page?  Logs in `logs` directory are not helpful.

```
D, [2022-10-08T10:55:17.011607 #2571] DEBUG -- :   SOLR Request (19.4ms)  [ path=update par
ameters={} ]
```

Comment: Go to 'http://localhost:8983/solr/` - i.e. to your Solr installation. I think that log is your ruby log, not the Solr log.

Comment: Thank you. I can access the Solr admin now.  I am checking `Logging` tab and I don't see any errors related to the reindexing

Comment: Then it sounds like your issue probably is on the Ruby/Sunspot side; coult it be possible that it never gets to the Solr side at all?

Comment: Well that could be possible however, I don't know enough to say that for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the error handling in `sunspot` package.

There was a bad date entry `empty space` for one of the records that failed when Date.parse() tried to parse the date.

I had to debug the sunspot code to figure out the field that resulted in this issue. After correcting the record reindexing worked.